# Are there "magic functions" for powershell objects?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, magic-function

In PHP, there are "magic methods" that exist if you need them to. An example of this is the `__toString()` method which is used to echo out a specific string if a piece of code attempts to echo the object. This is an example using PHP:

```
<?php
// Declare a simple class
class TestClass
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$class = new TestClass('Hello');
echo $class;
?>
```

Which would return:

```
Hello
```

Is there a "magic function" that will do this in Powershell?

Comment: I don't know much PHP but... How is that "magic"? Existing if you need it to? It seems to me like a simple function override, the same way that you would do in Javascript or Java, so it would always exist if you declared it.

Comment: I think virtually all PowerShell objects provide a method `ToString()`, if that's your question.

Comment: @Renan I call in a magic function, because that's what PHP calls them: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php .

In my case, I am going to create objects with a lot of different properties. I would want to shorten my code, using something like `Write-Output $MyObj`, which would then echo `"My Custom String"`. I could modify the string to whatever I want, which could just be a summary of the object using some of it's properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All default PSObjects in PowerShell have a ToString() method, and if you're creating your custom objects in script (and not code), then you are going to have this method already present. All you need to to is override the ToString() method using Add-Member.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912827/how-to-set-the-default-tostring-on-a-locally-created-psobject) for an exact description of this.

You can see what members your custom object has by piping an instance of the object to Get-Member.

Comment: This works, but I was looking for a way to do it without having to use `echo $MyObject.ToString()`. If I can't figure out a way to do it like this `echo $MyObject`, this is definitely the best option. Thanks!

Comment: Just do "$MyObject" -- putting the object in quotes causes PowerShell to automatically invoke the ToString() method. Really any time that PowerShell needs to represent the object as text, it's calling ToString(). I can't think of a case where you'd need to invoke the ToString() method yourself. Give it a try and I think you'll be happy with the results.