# In Powershell does Write-Host call any method on piped object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What manipulation on piped data/objects does Write-Host do?

in my case if I do `$xmlContent` it will output a table of objects and if I do `$xmlContent | Write-Host` it will output the actual XML. When I do `$xmlContent.ToString()` it's not the same output as what gets produced by Write-Host. Hence the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be because ToString() is [from the underlying PSObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569069(v=vs.85).aspx), giving you a string representation of the object.
Hence, the result changes if you type the object. 
Then ToString() will depend on whatever you typed it as. And Write-Host will call ToString().

I tried 3 scenarios to make the difference observable:
[Last scenario is from Shay Levy's post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913237/7152407)

```
$untyped = Get-Content 'some.xml'
$untyped.ToString()
$pureDoc | Write-Host 

[xml]$typed =  Get-Content 'some.xml'
$typed.ToString()
$typed | Write-Host 

$pso = new-object psobject -property @{ name = 'bob'; job = 'janitor' }
$pso | add-member scriptmethod ToString { 'he is a {0}, he is' -f $this.job } -force 
$pso.ToString()
$pso | Write-Host
```

Output is:

```
System.Object[]
[XML omitted for brevity]
#document
#document
he is a janitor, he is
he is a janitor, he is
```

You see how Write-Host returns whatever becomes the implementation of  ToString()?

Answer (score 2):

`Write-Host` does a few things which are usually counter-intuitive or not the best way to do things, so I discourage you from using it. Instead, check out `Write-Verbose`, and `Write-Output` (or just try `Get-Help Write-*` to see all the possibilities).

**INPUT:**

`Write-Host` changes the input in a way that can be unexpected. When outputting a `string`, `int` or other familiar types, it will output the content of that input. However, as I'm sure you saw and were confused by, there are some types which `Write-Host` will not output content of, instead, it will just output the input's **type**. Which is pretty useless in most cases.

**OUTPUT:**

`Write-Host` outputs in the same format as writing the input by itself, or writing `return` in a function. These three can be used equivalently for a string type, for example:

```
$str

Write-Host $str

return $str #in context of a function
```

Note once again that they are equivalent for `string` types as well as some others, but `Write-Host` may manipulate the input in strange ways for other types.

In general, it is discouraged to use `Write-Host`. To debug/output to console, use `Write-Verbose`. To output to a pipeline or out of a function, write the variable by itself. This will output the nice dictionary-style format we are used to using in powershell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $dict

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key                            value
{test, test2}                  1
```

Compared to:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> write-host $dict
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```